# Is there a way of giving each div a unique id without actually typing it every time?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

My code looks like this:

```css
.wrapper {
    width: 140px;
}
.box {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
    border-radius: 4px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.box_top {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    background-color: #fff;
    min-height: 70px;
}
.box_top img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.box_content {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%: padding: 5px 15px;
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
}
.box_title,
.box_description,
.price,
.button {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 0;
}
.box_title {
    font-size: 18px;
}
.button {
    line-height: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #333;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="box" id="product_1">
        <div class="box_top">
            <img src="http://oregonaitc.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/potato.jpg" alt="Product 1" />
        </div>
        <div class="box_content">
            <a class="box_title">TITLE</a>
            <p class="box_description">
                Description
            </p>
            <a class="price">$10</a>
            <a class="button" id="product_1_add">
            Add to cart
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I want to do is add a unique ID to every  element in order to be able to target each box individually using jQuery later on.

Sort of like `<div class="box" id="product_1">`, `<div class="box" id="product_2">` and so on.

The problem is that on my page there are numerous product boxes like this one, and it would take a lot of time to add a unique id to every element by hand. How can I use jQuery or PHP to solve this problem?

Comment: Presumably you're generating your HTML dynamically in PHP right? Probably looping through a list of products and generating output? That would be the place to generate a dynamic ID.

Comment: use a counter variable and increment in loop

Comment: Why? I ask because it seems like it might be better to take the traversal route, something like `$('.button').click(function() { var box = $(this).closest('.box'); });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just loop through all your products and echo them out.
I've made the following assumptions:
1. Your pulling directly from a database
2. The pull is in the form of a 2D array
3. Keys from this data are "Image","Title","Description" and "Price"

```
<?php
$productArray = array(); //The array of your product data
for ($i=1; $i=<count($productArray); i++;){
echo '<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box" id="product_'.$i.'">
    <div class="box_top">
      <img src="http://oregonaitc.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/'.$productArray[$i-1]['Image'].'" alt="Product '.$i.'" />
      </div>
      <div class="box_content">
      <a class="box_title">'.$productArray[$i-1]['Title'].'</a>
      <p class="box_description">         
      '.$productArray[$i-1]['Description'].'
      </p>
      <a class="price">'.$productArray[$i-1]['Price'].'</a>
      <a class="button" id="product_'.$i.'_add">
        Add to cart
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use jQuery for adding the IDs

```
$([selector_to_your_divs]).each(function(index) {
    $(this).attr("id","id_prefix_"+index); 
});
```